# Install IRI full node on my PC Ubuntu: shows canceled

Tags: iri-node, iota-network, iot

I want to install IRI full node IoTA on my PC with Ubuntu bionic 18.04 with core i3  and 8GB RAM.
I entered the following command to install IRI:

```
sudo bash < <(curl -s https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nuriel77/iri-playbook/feat/docker/fullnode_install.sh)
```

I follow this toturial from the offical website of IoTA:
[enter link description here](https://iri-playbook.readthedocs.io/en/master/getting-started-quickly.html#getting-started-quickly)

The output of command:
[image]
[image]
It can be seen it shows "canceled". I don't know what I have missed!
Is there any tutorials helps me to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. As stated in the instructions, you should run the installation as root by becoming root (sudo su), else it doesn't get the correct ENVs for root.
2. The correct link for the most up-to-date documentation is https://iri-playbook.readthedocs.io/en/feat-docker/getting-started-quickly.html

Note that the command only has one `<`, i.e.:

```
bash <(curl -s https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nuriel77/iri-playbook/feat/docker/fullnode_install.sh)
```

Comment: in particular, the variant with two `<` would send the script via stdin, which makes it impossible to also use stdin for interactive prompts.